# S-Pen only (touch screen disabled)?

Tags: samsung, touchscreen, input-methods, stylus, s-pen

I take hand written notes on my Samsung Tablet S3, as well as my Samsung Note 8 phone, using the S Pen.  Both are on Android 9.  Palm rejection and other accidental touches are mostly rejected, but not perfectly.

I would like to have a way to turn off the capacitive touch screen (that registers finger touches) but leave the S Pen detection on.  In this state, the tablet or phone would respond to the S Pen only, and ignore all other screen touches.

I know there are apps that can perform this feature, but they mostly come with unacceptably broad permissions, including full access to the network, reading contents on the device, etc.  This seems like something that should be built into the OS, but I have not found it.

I should add that I own a paid version of Tasker, but am not very good at programming it, in case someone has a good solution for Tasker.

Any advice or hacks?